# Tor by SSH / http proxy

Tags: 16.04, ssh, proxy, tor, localhost

Is there a program that i can use to access my socks5(Tor) ,by simulating a servor SSH or http(s) proxy.

Because torsocks doesn't work with some web browsers.

The connection should look like this:

local host <--> https proxy / SSH <--> tor <--> internet

Comment: Which browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo -s 
apt-get install privoxy 
echo "forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 ." >>/etc/privoxy/config
systemctl restart privoxy
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ELinks#Tor_usage